# Mongoose Read Preference Tags Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, replicaset

I have a Mongo replica set, with a master in the US, and a slave in Europe, as well as Node server instances in the same locations running Node with Mongoose.

The Mongo instances have tags, the US one `{"location":"us"}` and the European one `{"location":"eu"}`. I'm trying to perform a read operation from the European Node server. When `readPreference` is set to `master`, reads take 450ms on average. When it's set to `nearest`, it takes 70ms.

Here's what the Mongoose/Mongo connection URL looks like in the latter case:

```
?replicaSet=MyReplicaSet&readPreference=nearest
```

Now, I want to test read preference tags. For that, I modify the query to look like this:

```
?replicaSet=MyReplicaSet&readPreference=nearest&readPreferenceTags=location:us
```

However, even though it should now select the nearest node from the US rather than Europe, the average read time is still around 70ms, far from the expected 450ms.

The Mongo URI is passed as the first argument to the `mongoose.createConnection` call. I'm using Mongoose version `4.4.5`, which, as a dependency, uses Mongodb version `2.1.16`.

Does that version of Mongoose not support passing in readPreferenceTags through the connection URI, or am I doing something entirely wrong?

Comment: It would appear that `readPreference=nearest` is overriding the tag-set selection of `readPreferenceTags=location:us`, so try removing the conflicting option. The options should pass through directly, but of course you can always try connecting with a small program just using the basic node driver to verify that there is in fact no interference.

Comment: I'm afraid that's wrong. Here's an excerpt from the read preference documentation: "However, the nearest read mode, when combined with a tag set, selects the matching member with the lowest network latency." Source: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/#tag-sets

Comment: Wrong person to say "that's wrong" to. Just actually set the URI options that way and try again. Then tell me how wrong it is.